# Join tables by filling gaps with previous data

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
DATE         ENGINEERS
----------------------
2014-03-06   6
2014-03-10   7
```

In which I register when the number of engineers change. For example, in this case I had 6 engineers, but on the 10th March, I hired one more, so I have 7 from then onwards.

I have another table with the appointments per day

```
DATE         APPOINTMENTS
-------------------------
2014-03-06   4
2014-03-07   5
2014-03-10   5
2014-03-11   6
```

How can I get a view like this, which combines the appointments and the number of engineers per day?

```
DATE         APPOINTMENTS    ENGINEERS
--------------------------------------
2014-03-06   4               6
2014-03-07   5               6
2014-03-10   5               7
2014-03-11   6               7
```

Comment: But the output doesnt make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I could do :

```
SELECT t2.at, t2.appointments, (@n := IFNULL(t1.engineers, @n)) FROM t2
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT t.at, t1.engineers
  FROM t1
  JOIN t2 t ON t1.at = t.at
) t1 ON t1.at = t2.at;
```

I am sure there is something better out there, as the redondant `JOIN` could not be needed, but I could not find it.

It actually use a sql variable to get the last value if there is no corresponding entry in the engineers table.

Don't forget to run `SET @n = 0;`.

[The corresponding sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a08aa/22)

Comment: The output for engineer column is still wrong but i really liked your try. I am still not able to figure it out

Comment: @AshReva checkout my edit, `SET @n = 0;` fixes it :)

Comment: Yes it is correct but i doubt if OP could need this to set something. Somehow i feel the expected output dont make much sense. Do you agree?

Comment: It makes sense, I think the OP want to know how many engineers are available when he has appointements.

Comment: Yes but repeating the data doesnt make sense

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! One additional problem though, how can I create a view out of this? Views don't work with nested queries, and I don't know how/where to set up @n=0.

Comment: @AshReva, why it doesn't make sense?

Comment: @imBeta I don't think you can create a view from this, as it uses a variable. To set `@n` to `0`, just run a query as you'd do an insert or an update. EG in php : `PDO::exec('SET @n = 0;');`

Comment: @Thomas Ruiz, thanks, I'll have to look for another solution then, although this is indeed useful for the future!

Comment: Sorry I can't vote up guys, I dont't have enough 'reputation'